# ArgMin over intervals and discrete sets

Tags: mathematical-optimization, constraint, sets, intervals

I was playing with `ArgMin` but I'm not sure how to use it for constrained optimization.

For example,

```
ArgMin[x^2, x]
```

returns `0` as expected, but,

```
ArgMin[x^2, x ∈ Interval[{1, 2}]]
```

gives the error

> ArgMin::objfs: The objective function `{Subscript[x, 1]^2}` should be scalar-valued.

I know it works using,

```
ArgMin[{x^2, x <= 2, x >= 1}, x]
```

but what's the point of intervals if you can't use them as sets/domains? Even more puzzling, it seems that it does not handle finite sets,

```
P = {-2, -1, 1, 2};
ArgMin[x, x ∈ P]
```

gives the error

> ArgMin::ivar: `x ∈ {-2, -1, 1, 2}` is not a valid variable.

Anyone has an idea why `ArgMin` does not seem to handle those simple cases?

Comment: As already noted, a list of numbers is **not** a valid domain that can be fed to `Element[]`. Nevertheless, try this: `With[{P = {-2, -1, 1, 2}}, ArgMin[{x, AnyTrue[P, EqualTo[x]]}, x]]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

ArgMin[x^2, x ∈ Interval[{1, 2}]]

(* ArgMin::objfs: The objective function {Subscript[x, 1]^2} should be scalar-valued.

ArgMin[x^2, x ∈ Interval[{1, 2}]] *)
```

The subscript in the error message indicates that it was expecting a vector. Use

```
ArgMin[x^2, {x} ∈ Interval[{1, 2}]]

(* 1 *)
```

For the second example,

```
P = {-2, -1, 1, 2};

RegionQ[P]

(* False *)
```

`P` is not a region. Define a region

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[Or @@ Thread[var == P], var];
```

Then

```
ArgMin[x, {x} ∈ reg]

(* -2 *)
```

Comment: Nice all this works! I get the set {x} instead of x, but could you explain a little the definition of a region you wrote? This seemed very esoteric to me, especially to just use a set as a region, it should be more straightforward, shouldn't it?

Comment: Read the documentation for [`ImplicitRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html)

Comment: Sure, also the documentation of Thread and @@. I understand the construction now, but shouldn't there be a more straightforward way than using an implicit region with writing out explicitly ```var==-2 || var==-1```... ? For example, I feel this should have worked but it does not:
```reg = ImplicitRegion[MemberQ[P, var], var]```

Comment: @OlivierMassicot - Issues on how it should work you'll have to take up with Wolfram

Comment: Well, that's no explanation on why it does not work.

Comment: It does not work because `ImplicitRegion[MemberQ[P, var], var]` evaluates to `EmptyRegion[1]` since `MemberQ[{-2, -1, 1, 2}, var]` evaluates to `False`, i.e., it cannot have a symbolic value. The logical expressions can return symbolic expressions.